# TeXlive 2013 / LuaLaTeX: Class Resource not found

Tags: luatex, texlive

I have a document class in my `~/texmf/tex/latex/CLASSNAME` directory named `CLASSNAME.cls`. In the same folder is an PDF file, named `LogoNewDesign.pdf`. The logo is used in the class file in an `\includegraphics`:

```
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{LogoNewDesign}
```

I've run `mktexlsr` and `texhash`, both as user and as root (TeXlive 2013 is installed to `/usr/local/texlive/2013`, available to all users). Additionally, I run `texhash ~/texmf`.

When I compile a TeX file using the class with `pdflatex`, everything is fine. The logo is correctly included. Doing the same thing with `lualatex`, the error `! LaTeX Error: File 'LogoNewDesign' not found.` comes up.

With LuaLaTeX in TeXlive 2012 the class worked before upgrading to 2013.

My `texlive.profile` looks like that:

```
TEXDIR /usr/local/texlive/2013
TEXMFCONFIG ~/.texlive2013/texmf-config
TEXMFHOME ~/texmf
TEXMFLOCAL /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFSYSCONFIG /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config
TEXMFSYSVAR /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var
TEXMFVAR ~/.texlive2013/texmf-var
```

I think I have a configuration/file list problem somewhere, but I can't figure out where to look. My `texmf.cnf` is empty (only the default comment lines are there), as it was with TeXlive 2012.

Comment: Why do you have any `.cls` or `.pdf` there?  (Note: I'm still on TL2012, but that still seems very odd.)  Also, what happens if you move the two folders to the more usual `~/texmf/tex/latex` folder?

Comment: @jon - I moved the class file and the image to `~/texmf/tex/latex/CLASSNAME`. The problem persists. I edited the question accordingliy.

Comment: *Never* do `texhash ~/texmf`. Remove the `ls-R` file thus created.

Comment: I tested a similar configuration and it works on my system

Comment: Remove teh `ls-R` file as @egreg said, test again with `\listfiles` in the preamble, and examine and perhaps post the `.log` along with a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl))

Comment: Since the last LuaTeX update for TeXlive 2013, LuaLaTeX finds the pdf file again without any problems. But now, font loading takes forever. But this seems to be another construction area.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue fixed in the current release, ad detailed in comments.